# Обработка ответа после отправки Post запросов через ajax на js

Tags: javascript, ajax, post

Использую `api` одного сайта.

Отправка `Post` запроса:

```
<input type="button" value="post" onclick="SendPost();">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://scriptjava.net/source/scriptjava/scriptjava.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function SendPost() {
        // отправляю POST запрос
        $$a({
            type:'post', // тип запроса: get,post либо head
            url:'http://catcut.net/api/create.php', // url адрес файла обработчика
            data:{
                'longurl':'https://vk.com', 'id':'256', 'advsurfing':'1', 'comment':'text', 'hash':'3d9f6478ba650803011eebcc7bccb5b3301f7d26'
            }, // параметры запроса
            response:'html', // тип возвращаемого ответа text либо xml
            success:function(data) { // возвращаемый результат от сервера
                $$('result', $$('result').innerHTML + '<br />' + data);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Запрос уходит, на сервисе вносятся изменения, но ответ я не получаю.
Как правильно обработать ответ? в ответе приходит только одна строка. Есть ли возможность в ответе получить содержимое всей страницы?

Comment: Вам в этой строке возвращается всё что ответил сервер.

Comment: @Mihanik71 дело в том что строка пустая приходит, либо я не правильно её отображаю

Comment: Попробуйте просто `console.log(data);` или в инспекторе посмотреть

Comment: @Mihanik71 в инспекторе - "14:00:51.390 Запрос из постороннего источника заблокирован: Политика одного источника запрещает чтение удаленного ресурса на http://catcut.net/api/create.php. (Причина: отсутствует заголовок CORS 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin').1 (неизвестен)"

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка CORS 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' говорит о том, что аяксово обращаться к `http://catcut.net/api/create.php` можно только с того же сервера, где опубликован `catcut.net` или с доверенных серверов.

Если это ваш проект и вы можете поменять список доверенных серверов для CORS - сделайте это.

В противном случае вы не сможете аяксово обращаться к этому url. Но вы можете обращаться к API на бекенде:

1. Аяксово обращаетесь к своему серверу и проекту;
2. На бекенде в своем проекте обращаетесь к API `catcut.net`;
3. На бекенде получаете ответ и отдаете его аяксово на фронтенд;
4. На фронтенде принимаете в `success: function(data)`

Comment: нет, проект не мой. Просто нужно сделать запрос и как-то получить ответ) Обычной формой с инпутами получается, но меня перекидывает на страницу самого сервиса с api. А мне нужно просто сделать запрос и получить ответ на этой же страницу без перезагрузки

Comment: Придется тогда залезть в бэкенд и запрос к внешнему API написать там. На фронте в таком случае у вас поменяется только url - вы будете аяксово обращаться не к внешнему url, а к url вашего же сайта, к бэкенду, который уже будет делать запрос к внешнему API.

Comment: дело в том, что запрос то обрабатывается нормально (вижу это в их админке) но мне нужно просто ответ обработать

Comment: @sbaikov, `А мне нужно просто сделать запрос и получить ответ` - увы, ответ вам прочитать не даёт ограничение, накладываемое [принципом одинакового источника/same origin policy](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Правило_ограничения_домена), если кратко - это нужно чтобы каждый посещаемый сайт не мог через js читать вашу почту и соц.сети. В ответе всё правильно написано - **запросы к этому API должны делаться на сервере!!1**